# Is there any way to hide paths in terminal in VScode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm a little new to VS and was wondering if there's any way to remove the path to the .c file.

As it is, it's way too cluttered to actually read the output.

[image: Here's]Here's what my terminal currently looks like.

Comment: Could you paste the code from your terminal here to complete your question?

Comment: No, it is to make sure that the files are located independent of the current directory in the terminal

Comment: Don't use space or quotes in file/directory names

Comment: @Egel I didn't think that was relevant. It's just a Hello world code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths instead of absolute. For example, if your current directory is `/home/aayush/Desktop/bucky's tuts` and your source file `Hello_world.c` is there:

```
gcc Hello_world.c -o Hello_world && ./Hello_world
```

Remember that it won't work if you has another directory as current.